# Unable to crop image with flexbox

Tags: html, css

I have an image sized exactly, but I can't get it to crop vertically. I end up with empty white space with image overflow, or the flexbox extends itself to the image extents. How can I resolve this so the image will crop to match the height of the rest of my elements in a responsive way?

[image]

---

The white box is the area I would like to remove so that the image gets cropped to match the other elements without scaling the image. However I can't figure out how to achieve this. (assuming I can with vanilla CSS)

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  font-family: var(--fontStyleStandard);
}

.mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: left;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: var(--mainBgColor);
}

.formContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.innerContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: var(--modulecolor1);
  position: relative;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bodyContainer {
  display: inherit;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.fieldContainer {
  padding: 0 0 0 3rem;
  background-color: var(--modulecolor1);
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 5px 2px 5px rgb(24, 12, 27);
  width: 100%;
}

.leftBanner.fixed {
  display: flex;
  /* background:border-box no-repeat left / contain fixed url("../img/sideImage2.png"); */
  /* max-height: 100vh; */
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top left;
}

.leftBanner>img {
  display: inherit;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 45%;
  min-height: 45%;
}

.formHeading {
  background-color: var(--modulecolor2);
}
```

```html
<!-- Add your site or application content here -->
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="leftBanner fixed">
    <img src="./img/sideImage2.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="bodyContainer">
    <div class="formContainer">
      <h4 class="formHeading fontstyle1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus, totamimpeditcupiditate cumque atque aperiam delectus mollitia rem error incidunt consequuntur reiciendis asperiores id eveniet. In nemo alias debitis unde?</h4>

      <div class="buttonContainer"><button class="styled" form="signUp" type="submit">Create Account</button>
        <div>Already Have an account? <a href="">Log in</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) presented as a StackSnippet would probably be helpful, specifically including a working `<img>` link, because the provided code snippets don't produce something that really looks much like your screenshot.  That said, I think you should try applying `object-fit: cover` to your `<img>` tag, rather than the containing `<div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this cropping,
First, you could set the height of your `.leftBanner` to be the same as your `.bodyContainer` This is fine, though it will not be as responsive, and I also imagine your `.bodyContainer` will have more content in it, thus removing the set crop.
Instead I'd do the following

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  font-family: var(--fontStyleStandard);
}

.mainContainer {
  background-color: var(--mainBgColor);
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: left;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
.bodyContainer {
  display: inherit;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: auto;
}
.formContainer {
  /*Change the FormContainer to a flexbox and set to your intended Height/Max-Height */
  display: flex;
  /*This will be a flex Row  */
  flex-direction: row;
  height:fit-content;
  max-height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.form{
  background-color:green;
  height:fit-content;
}
.leftBanner.fixed {
  /*set this image Height to 100%  filling the intended height of the formContainer give it a min-height so it will always have a size*/
  height:100%;
  min-height:200px;
  background: border-box no-repeat left / contain fixed 
    url("https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1167895713/photo/abstract-galaxy-watercolor-backgrounds.jpg?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=ivNkiy9Bq_CMEAEoGrDNQuilHll53fhAn-BKTgB9dqU=");
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}

.leftBanner > img {
  display: inherit;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 45%;
  min-height: 45%;
}

.formHeading {
  background-color: var(--modulecolor2);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="bodyContainer">
      <div class="formContainer">
    <!--Place the Banner inside the form this will restrict its max height to the height of the form-->
        <div class="leftBanner fixed">
          <img src="./img/sideImage2.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class='form'>
          <h4 class="formHeading fontstyle1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus, totamimpeditcupiditate cumque atque aperiam delectus mollitia rem error incidunt consequuntur reiciendis asperiores id eveniet. In nemo alias debitis unde?</h4>

          <div class="buttonContainer"><button class="styled" form="signUp" type="submit">Create Account</button>
            <div>Already Have an account? <a href="">Log in</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

By Placing your banner image inside the form, it's max-height will always be the height of the form. Thus cropping it to the correct height.

This becomes problematic with using the `background-image` setting of the `.leftBanner` because `background-images` do not have set heights, so you will need to input a height/min-height to that class in order for it to register as an active div with dimensions. Or use the `<img></img>` to set your background image, and give it an `object-fit:cover`

The above solution will work, so long as you don't mind setting a min-height to the form.

Comment: Okat from what I can see this is the best method for complex situations. Essentially the image has to be inside the element to be used as the boundary for it to work properly. In my original file I have more containers/forms etc, so I may just rewrite the css with this technique in mind. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A simple construct with `position: absolute;` and `overflow: hidden;` should do the task, if I understood what you're trying to do correctly. It's absolutely responsive:

```
.mainContainer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
}

.leftBanner.fixed {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.leftBanner img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image: cropped responsive giraffe]

Comment: I didn't know about `overflow`. So this will work in simple situations but my original file is a bit more complicated. adjusting screen size resulted in the image stretching akwardly with your method.

Comment: Only if you have some leftover styles that affect the left column. That would need to be cleaned up. Then the image would stretch proportionally.

Comment: but that's the thing, I don't want the image to stretch at all.

Comment: It will stick to its proportions. But flexboxes are responsive – so the image will grow with the parent container and be cropped at different positions according to the size of the content on the right. If you don't want the image to grow at all, remove the flex-grow from the parent container in the left column.